# Avoiding/cleaning buffer artifacts in R

Tags: r, buffer, sf

I'm trying to create a buffer around a multi-linestring object with `st_buffer`.

Here's my initial attempt:

`library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(rmapshaper)`

`proj_sahel <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=9.71 +lat_2=22.58 +lon_0=2.81"`

`boundaries <- ne_download(scale = 10, category = "cultural", type = "admin_0_boundary_lines_land", returnclass = "sf")`

`buffer50 <- boundaries %>% filter(adm0_a3_l == "MLI" & adm0_a3_r %in% c("BFA", "NER")) %>%
st_transform(crs = proj_sahel) %>%
st_buffer(dist = 50000) %>%
st_cast("POLYGON")`

It works fine except for the unfortunate artifact right in the middle of the buffer zone as you can see below: [image: buffer artifact]

I tried simplifying the geometry before and after `st_transform` with `ms_simplify`, it didn't make any difference. How can I avoid this or clean it after the fact?

Comment: That is not an artifact, you in fact, have two geometries in your line data and the function is buffering both of them. Have you looked at the dim() of the boundaries object or the result of applying the dplyr::filter function to it? You could try rgeos::gBuffer with byid = FALSE.

Comment: Where is `proj_sahel` defined?

Comment: Please don't use `library(tidyverse)` - be minimal and only specify packages you really need. I think here you are only using `library(dplyr)`. Attaching all the tidyverse packages is not best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the union of your buffered features:

```
> plot(buffer$geom)
```

[image]

```
> plot(st_union(buffer$geom))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't realise this. As for the comment about best practices and the definition of `proj_sahel` you're right, I do make use of the rest of the packages, this was just a lazy copy/paste of a tiny portion of code. I'll edit the question.